# Active Directory Tool, Bulk Home Drive Migration

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory

I am looking for a good Active Directoy tool to help migrate user's Home drives and
possibly Profiles from one File Server to the next in the forest (diiferent domain)
and the tool should be able to set permissions on the new home drives and point
sthe users home folder to the new location.

I am doing this in bulk, so a bulk tool that generates report will be great!

Answer (score 1):

File Server Migration Tool from Microsoft should do the job ([link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d00e3eae-930a-42b0-b595-66f462f5d87b&displaylang=en))

Comment: Does this tool have to be installed on the server?

Comment: Reading the whitepaper, it doesn't look like the toolkit has to be installed on either server - just *a* server, and has to be run using an account that is a local admin on both source and target servers.

Comment: It also appears that it will not change anything in their AD accounts, but if you migrate the server name or mess around with DFS, you might not need to do that. Otherwise, you can just script something with a BAT script with dsmod, that's what I've done in the past.

Comment: i assumed that user SIDs were not being messed with (you say you have another domain), you can install this on any server and it's typically used to migrate shares (and permissions to those shares).

Comment: Is DFS a must or can it operate without DFS?

Comment: last time i used it was to transfer shares from one file server to another, afaik DFS is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling something in powershell should only be a dozen or so lines of code for something like this.

Comment: Any sample to help?